# Symfony2, Expire backend session

Tags: session, symfony, backend, session-timeout

I am programming a Symfony2 web application and I have a backend bundle, in which the user is authenticated using an emergent window. What I need is that the session expires using a timeout or when I close de browser. Now it doesn't...

Any idea?

Comment: I assume you're using HTTP authentication, am I right? Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233507/how-to-log-out-user-from-web-site-using-basic-authentication

Comment: I don't want that the user has to click anywhere. Is it possible to set a timeout or something like this? I have read this answer but I don't really know where to add the line he says (RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}])... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530684/symfony2-in-memory-users-provider-issue/13537358#13537358